# how to find newton iteration for each of initial points

Tags: matlab, loops

```
 function p = newton_hw(p0,tol,Nmax)

%NEWTON'S METHOD: Enter f(x), f'(x), x0, tol, Nmax
f = @(x) x*cos(x)-((sin(x))^2);
fp= @(x) -x*sin(x)+ cos(x)-2*sin(x)*cos(x);
p = p0 - (f(p0)/fp(p0));
y1=f(p);
fprintf('y1=%f',y1)
i = 1;
while (abs(p - p0) >= tol)

    p0 = p;
    p = p0 - f(p0)/fp(p0);
    i = i + 1;
    if (i >= Nmax)
        fprintf('Fail after %d iterations\n',Nmax);
        break
    end

    y=f(p);
    fprintf('a=%f,y=%f,\n',p,y);
end

end
```

This is my question:

How to iterate for each of `p0 = 0,.1,.2,...,49,5`.

Comment: how to iterate over the interval I = [0,5], at every 0.1

Answer (score 1):

Iterating using user's step can be done this way:

```
for i = 0:0.1:5
```

Also any indexing can be done the same way: `x = [0:2:50]`.

If your function works correctly (I suppose so), we can go this way:

```
k = 1;
for i = 0:0.1:5
res(k) = newton_hw(i,0.001,1000);
k = k+1;
end
```

But also we can do it at one line - style:

```
res = arrayfun( @(x) newton_hw(x, 0.001, 1000), I)
```

Comment: any suggestion where to insert for loop into my program? or do I need to create new program with for loop?

Comment: @AlqoshHazkeal There are three common ways to use it:
1. Save function as .m file with the same name (newton_hw.m) and then use it in your script or in another function (they must be located at the same directory)
2. You can use it as local function: see more about it here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions.html
3. And if you use 2016b or newer you can create functions inside script file: look here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/local-functions-in-scripts.html

Comment: @rayryeng What can we consider as vectorization and what is a not? Can you give me some rule?

Comment: Vectorization is anything that does not use a loop - basically anything that performs SIMD (Single Instruction Multiple Data) operations.  `arrayfun` internally performs a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for correcting your vectorized assertion. I've voted up now because the post now in its entirety is valid.